# Confirm event completion whilst invoking REST API in an outlook JS add-in

Tags: javascript, rest, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am building a JS add-in that simply forwards a message with the added comment 'STOP' to a defined address upon clicking a button in the ribbon. In order to forward I call the REST API with a `POST` request.

When adding `event.completed()` at the end of the function, with `(event)` as parameter, the getCallbackTokenAsync does not run at all.

Instead, without it, the add-in forwards the message properly but the info bar does not disapear and the script keeps running on a loop:

Info bar to signal that script is running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGa2K.png

Any ideas on how I should properly handle the `event.completed()` when calling the REST API?

```js
// the function sendAsStops is called directly from the manifest file
function sendAsStops(event) {
  console.log("Initialising STOP command.");
  var restHost = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl;
  var itemId = getItemRestId();
  console.log(itemId);
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      console.log('Sending email...');
     var accessToken = result.value;
      console.log(result);
      var getMessageUrl = restHost + '/v2.0/me/messages/' + itemId + '/forward';
        $.ajax({
          url: getMessageUrl,
          type: 'post',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken },
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify({
            'Comment': 'STOP',
            'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': { 'Address': 'name@address.com' }}],
          })
         }).done(function() {
           console.log("Stop successfully forwarded.");
         }).fail(function(error) {
           console.log("Failed to send");
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Unable to proceed. Ref: " + result.status);
      return false;
    }
  });
  event.completed();
}

function getItemRestId() {
  console.log("Getting item ID...");
  if (Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === 'OutlookIOS') {
    console.log("ID ready to use.");
    return Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
  } else {
    console.log('Converting ID...');
    return Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
      Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
      Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.completed()` must be called at the end of the execution of your add-in. Calling `event.completed()` is terminating your add-in, so any asynchronous calls (such as `getCallbackTokenAsync` callback in this case) gets automatically terminated and cleaned up. Hence, you do not see the add-in forwarding the message.

Call `event.completed()` after your entire add-in execution is complete. Something like:

```
       $.ajax({
          url: getMessageUrl,
          type: 'post',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken },
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify({
            'Comment': 'STOP',
            'ToRecipients': [{'EmailAddress': { 'Address': 'name@address.com' }}],
          })
         }).done(function() {
           console.log("Stop successfully forwarded.");
           event.completed();
         }).fail(function(error) {
           console.log("Failed to send");
           event.completed();
        });
```